# Environment variables not visible in configuration provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up database connection string for my Azure Devops Entity Framework database migration task.

My idea is not to publish config with database connections on git but to use environment variables to override app config with production settings (DB connection string).

When migration is started, set environment variable is not read by app, instead, default, dev connection string is used.

For example connection string entry is: `ConnectionStrings.Database`

I have set it like this: `set ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__Database=test`

I does not work.
When I set connection string in Visual Studio Debug properties it works properly.
I have included environment variables in app startup, as MS documentation suggests.

What is the difference between VS debugger set variables and console set ones?

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:
Visual Studio add's environment variables to `launchSettings.json`
[image]

Comment: I don't think you need the `ASPNETCORE`. Just `ConnectionStrings__Database` should do.

Comment: That part is trimmed by configuration provider, I have tested it in debugger, no matter what I set trough console EnvConfigurationProvider does not have enty in list. Are there any environment profiles? Like current user, machine or app context?

Comment: How are you setting the environment variables when you deploy your app? Are you on Linux?

Comment: We use Azure App Services, connection strings and other settings are set there (trough web UI), that is running on Ubuntu. Devops tasks are running Visual Studio 2017 windows agent.

Comment: It might be a case sensitivity issue. Have you tried `CONNECTIONSTRINGS__DATABASE`?

Comment: I might try that but I have written settings in correct case. Maybe capitalize all might work, but I doubt it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys this was a case of brain hiccup...
I did not push environment variable provider to branch so the Azure Devops task did not read them:

```
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
```

This is a bit embarrasing :-(
But it might help to someone in the future.
Thanx 8ytan for your comments.